# Using "and" to begin a sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Is it grammatically correct to use the word "and" as the first word in a sentence? Why or why not?

Comment: And why would it not be correct?

Comment: To restate my previous (and deleted) answer and example for this question: it is grammatically correct to do this. And why? Because you can do anything you like, so long as you are understood correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start a sentence with `And` if you want, but what follows must be a complete sentence.  In other words, if you take the `And` out, the sentence must still be complete; it's otherwise known as an independent clause.

Example

> Dorothy found her red slippers yesterday.
> And they were on her feet the whole time!
>
> Bob likes burgers.  And making burgers is what makes Bob happy.

There are other words to use as sentence starters that are considered somewhat taboo to use like: but, for, so, nor, yet, or...

> I believe Pluto is a planet.  Or maybe the scientists just want us to think that.

If you take the And out of any of those sentences... (or Or), there still remains a full complete sentence.

> Bob likes burgers.  Making burgers is what makes Bob happy.

Comment: Can you please give an example to make  it clearer. Thank you

Comment: check my update